# Change Symfony @ParamConverter annotation response message

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I cant find any documentation on how to change the response message from the @ParamConverter annotation.

Can I customize this message?

```
"message": "App\Entity\Object object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.",
"code": 404,
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not option to change this message because this should be visible only in dev environment. You can change what user see with custom error page.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html